# CCLocation with startMonitoringForRegion is not working anymore since iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cllocationmanager, cllocationcoordinate2d

I use this code becore iOS 10 and it worked well.

```
    //Start monitoring
    CLLocationCoordinate2D centre;
    centre.latitude = [latZone floatValue];
    centre.longitude = [lonZone floatValue];

    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:[[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:centre radius:[radiusZone floatValue] identifier:nameZone]];
```

But since the iOS 10 version, it doesn't work anymore.
It doesn't call didEnterRegion: didExitRegion: & didStartMonitoringForRegion:

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it by adding two keys in the info.plist :

```
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
```

And adding that two lines just before :

```
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
```